# R: Adding configuration options on package install

Tags: r, configuration, r-package

I am developing a simple R package in which I would like to specify some local configuration options on package install.  In particular, I would like the user to input a location on their computer on which to store package output data.

The package is most basically a random number generator.  When used, it will generate a new random number, check the user-specified data file to make sure that number has not been generated, then either generate a new number, or append the new number to the data file.

I believe I could come up with a way to do this, but I'm wondering if there is a formal way of specifying something like configuration options that are particular to the local installation.

I've scoured the internet for information about this but not found much. [This page](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Configure-and-cleanup) may be somewhat related but in the end I didn't think this was exactly what I would want.

Thank you for any advice you can give!

Comment: I suggest you deal with `options()`. When you package attaches/loads, look for an option (such as `"mypackage_cachefile"`); if the option is `NULL` (meaning the user did not specify it manually or in their `.Rprofile`), then determine a sane default. You can optionally include a `packageStartupMessage("new cachefile created <here>")` to advise the user. This requires nothing fancy at package *installation*, a feat I'm not certain is realistic or sustainable.

Comment: Ah, so I take it the `options` will be preserved between R sessions?

Comment: If the user properly adds the appropriate `options` to their `.Rprofile` then yes. If not, then your "sane default" will always be used *because you explicitly set it in your package*. This may need to be OS-specific, perhaps using a dotfile directory under `${HOME}` for unix-based, and perhaps something under `${APPDATA}` for windows.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want.  Thank you - this changes my life completely.